# Disabling Screen Rotation With Dynamic Orientation

Tags: java, android

I am currently using the following code in my manifest file to disable screen rotatation. This works great for phones and tablets, but it makes it look awkward on my Chromebook.

How can I turn off screen rotation, but use whichever orientation the app was opened with? So if the device was in portrait mode on app launch, I want to make that the only option for the session. If instead it was opened in landscape (like with a Chromebook), make that the only option for the session.

```
<activity android:name=".DisableScreenRotationAndroid" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check orientation and set to one you want before you set content view

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
} else setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: Where should I put this? In OnCreate?

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!